# If oil starts to smoke, does that mean it's already gone toxic?

Tags: oil, frying

When heating oil sometimes I notice smoke comes out and this sets home smoke detector off.  At this point I lower the fire or just add food.

Does this mean that it's already hit the smoking point and the oil should no longer be used?  If it hits smoking point and we lower the temperature is it still ok to use or is it only a problem with reuse?

Comment: I don't think the "is it toxic" question is really on-topic here. When you say "toxic" in this sense, it's more like "there are possibly some long-term health issues if you eat enough of it, we don't really know" (off-topic health) as opposed to "it risks making you sick *today*" (on-topic food safety). If you want to ask about the *flavor* when it's just started to smoke, because smoking/burning oil does make it taste bad eventually, that would be fine.

Comment: I think it's ok to ask about food safety here too right?  Almost all cooking guides make an issue out of smoking points.

Comment: Exactly: it's okay to ask about food safety, and as far as I know, smoking oil isn't a food safety issue. See my previous comment for health vs food safety; the fact that a lot of people like to talk about smoke points doesn't turn them into a food safety issue.

Comment: Agre with Cascabel, it has always been off topic on the site. Closing as a duplicate because it has been asked before.

Comment: Maybe there is legislation somewhere that puts limits on whatever "nasty" stuff is in manhandled oil, in commercial food preparation...  but that would be a far more specific question....